# MySQL retrieve employees presences

Tags: mysql

I need to retrieve the employees presences for the day. There are two states in the presences: **In & Out**. 
If the employee does not have a presence it should retrieve with the status of null.

I have two tables, `Employees` and `Presences` and I want to join them.

```
ID  |  name  
1      John
2      Julie
3      Anthony
4      Joseph
```

Now the presences table has the following data:

```
ID  |  employee_id  |  presence_date     |  presence_hour   |  Movement  
1      1               2016-08-30           08:55              In
2      2               2016-08-30           08:56              In
3      3               2016-08-30           08:57              In
4      1               2016-08-30           12:33              Out
5      2               2016-08-30           12:34              Out
```

As you can see in the presences data, the employee `Anthony` has not yet left the office and the employee `Joseph` has no entries in the table.

**The result I'm expecting**:

```
Employee  |  Movement  
John         Out  
Julie        Out
Anthony      In
Joseph       null
```

**The query I'm using**:

```
SELECT employee.name, presence.movement
FROM employees AS employee
LEFT JOIN presences AS presence ON presence.employee_id = employee.id
WHERE presence.presence_date = '2016-08-30' AND 
      employee.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY employee.id
ORDER BY employee.name, presence.id DESC
```

**The problems I'm facing**:

1. Joseph never appears in the data
2. `presence.id DESC` doesn't work

Comment: I suppose that "presence_date" column is a date-time column, right? Or is a string column?

Comment: 1. That’s how a LEFT JOIN works, so go check out the other types. 2. You want the “latest” record for each employee on that date, right? Then you should check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: The problem here is the where clause, to retrive null for Joseph you need to move the "presence.presence_date = '2016-08-30'" from where clause to join condition. So the left join will look like this: LEFT JOIN presences AS presence ON (presence.employee_id = employee.id and presence.presence_date = '2016-08-30'). Try this and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is caused by applying the date filter in the where criteria. The where criteria is applied **after** the join, thus eliminating any records for Joseph, since he was not present that day. Move the date criteria to the join condition instead.
2. You got the whole `group by` wrong, your query is against the sql standards because you have columns in the select list that are not in the group by list and are not subject of an aggregate function, such as `max()`. MySQL allows such queries under certain sql mode settings only. Use `max()` on the movement and group by on employee name and date fields.

Sample query, assuming you can only have 1 in and one out per employee per day:

```
SELECT employee.name, max(presence.movement) as movement
FROM employees AS employee
LEFT JOIN presences AS presence ON presence.employee_id = employee.id and date(presence.presence_date) = '2016-08-30'
WHERE employee.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY employee.name, date(presence.presence_date)
```

Comment: One thing, with your code I can't order by `presence.id` DESC...it always orders by ASC. How can I solve it?

Comment: As @GhostGambler explained it, there is not too much sense in ordering by presence.id. Including it in the order by clause would result in an invalid query again.

Answer (score 2):

For Joseph `presence.presence_date` is `null`, so it is not matched by `presence.presence_date = '2016-08-30'`.

The `order by presence.id` makes no sense to me. You are grouping by employee, so all matching rows in `presence` for that employee are merged together. You want to sort all those according to `presence.id` and select the most recent rows `movement` value? This does not work the way you wrote it. One solution would be to use `MAX(presence.id)` in your query to get the id of the most recent row of `presence` for the current employee and then join the `presence` table *again* to get the data you want.

```
SELECT a.name, b.movement
FROM (
  SELECT employee.name, MAX(presence.id) max_id
  FROM employees AS employee
  LEFT JOIN presences AS presence
    ON presence.employee_id = employee.id WHERE presence.presence_date = '2016-08-30' AND 
      employee.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
  GROUP BY employee.id
  ) a
LEFT JOIN presence b ON a.max_id = b.id
ORDER BY a.name
```

Although it might be not a good idea to assume that `most recent` is equivalent to `biggest id`, so one might select the row with the most recent date, but this is another "problem".